# Check if checkbox is checked not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I created a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="populatie" name="werking">
```

But when I try to check if it's checked, it doesn't do anything.

```
$("#opslaan").click(function(){

    if ($("#populatie").checked) {
    alert(hello); } 


})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: when I inspect element, and I checked it, I get:

```
checked true
```

So it's definetly checked...

Comment: Try: `$("#populatie")[0].checked` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Kp7Wu/). The `checked` property is for DOM nodes, not jQuery wrapped sets

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must pass `hello` as string to alert: `alert("hello")`, double quotation mark is missing

Answer (score 1):

Check it without jQuery:

```
$("#opslaan").click(function(){
    if(document.getElementById('populatie').checked) {
        alert("hello");
    }
});
```

It may even [be faster](http://jsperf.com/checking-checked)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#populatie")` returns a jQuery object, which does not have the checked property, it belongs to the dom element.

There are many ways to check it, one of the is to get the dom element reference and then check whether the property is set

Another is to use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is) and the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector)

```
$("#opslaan").click(function(){

    if ($("#populatie").is(':checked')) {
    alert(hello); } 


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop()` , `$("#populatie")` is a jQuery object,which doesn't have `checked` property

```
$("#opslaan").click(function(){    
    if ($("#populatie").prop('checked')) {
    alert('hello'); 
   }     
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Jah7W/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#populatie").is(":checked"){

    alert("");

}
```